# PHP Get in HTML File (test.html?name=Anything)

Tags: php, html, get

Is there a way to do a PHP Get from the URL in HTML?

I've made a form in HTML with an input.

The Input goes to a .php File with PHP Get.

But i want to use JQuery in these PHP File.

Can i use PHP Get to a HTML file?

(`test.html?name=Anything` instead of `test.php?name=Anything`)

Form:

```
<form method="get" action="cookies.html"> 
<input type="int" style="z-index: 1;" maxlength="7" name='menge' id="input"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How has my cookies.html to look like, to 'echo' with PHP the amount of cookies?

Comment: You can use `AddType` in .htaccess and set .html files to be parsed with PHP, that way PHP code will be executed in .html files as well.

Answer (score 1):

> But i want to use JQuery in these PHP File.

I think you don't actually understand how the web server works. PHP is executed on server side, while JQuery is a javascript library so it'is executed on the client side which is browser.

You make a request to server, there, the PHP part is executing and it is returning HTML code to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible plainly with HTML you need to use javascript something like this

```
    function getParameterByName(url) {
        name = url.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it to appear as an html extension it is possible.  But on the server itself the file will need to be php so the server will know to execute it. I would use [Apache mod_rewrite to do that.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)  However it doesn't really matter what the extension looks like once the server executes the php file the client will treat it just like an html file, and you can actually put javascript in a PHP file, the PHP and javascript would just execute at different times.

Answer (score 0):

Stop. You can't execute javascript code when php is executing. PHP is executed on the server and then it sends html and javascript to be displayed and executed on the client. What exactly are you trying to do, that you want to execute javascript on the server?

The answer to your question is no. You can't handle a form with an html file, but again: I don't understand why you would. I think you don't have a good understanding of this.

Comment: I could also use PHP but with PHP you can't design a page as good as with HTML. This is why i want to do it with an .html file. Or is there a way to use css, html and jquery in php without "echo" (because this is just messed up)

Comment: Yeah, in a php file you don't have to echo all the html. a php file doesn't have to start with <?php and end with ?>. you can just make a blank .php file and write html into it like you would in a .html file, then when you need to write php code you "break into" php; meaning write the <?php then your php code then the ?>. I strongly recommend phpacademy's login and register tutorial, especially this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2JNbMpF1O4&list=ECE134D877783367C7

Comment: actually watch the whole tutorial from the first video. it's an amazing tutorial for teaching templating and making a php-based website. here is a link to the tutorial as a whole: http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECE134D877783367C7